# Does kegging require a fridge

Tags: techniques, kegging, keg, kegerator

I was planning on building myself one of these for the summer: http://www.homebrewtalk.com/f51/portable-igloo-cooler-kegerator-172047-post1990392/

I currently bottle all my beer and don't own any kegging equipment.

Will I be able to do this without buying a second fridge?

In other words can kegged beer be stored in room temperature and then cooled down a night or so before serving? I don't have room in my fridge to keep the kegs there constantly.

Comment: related http://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/7835/storing-full-kegs-at-room-temperature/7836#7836

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have a buddy who did this for several years before investing in a beer fridge. Its not ideal, but it works.

The main difference to remember is that C02 becomes more soluble in liquid as the liquid drops in temperature, and less as it rises. So this means you'll need to push more C02 in to carbonate room temp kegs than cold ones.