# Aging full kegs out of fridge - carbonate now or later?

Tags: carbonation, kegging

I just bought my first two kegs, and don't yet have a fridge set up for them. Even when I do get my fridge set up I plan to have more kegs than will fit at once. When I fill them is it better to carbonate them at room temperature, or just purge all the air out of the head space with CO2 and wait to carbonate until they go in the fridge?

Comment: see http://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/7835/storing-full-kegs-at-room-temperature?rq=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have two lines coming from my CO2 regulator. My kegerator can only hold two kegs at a time. What I do is put two kegs in the kegerator and force carbonate them at serving temperature with lower pressure. Any additional kegs that I should happen to fill up stay outside of the kegerator for force carbonating with higher pressure.

Maybe you would be interested in doing something like this. If you have a dual body regulator I find it helpful to have the outside line for many tasks.